# Is “Illustrationist” a word?

Tags: is-it-a-word

Is “illustrationist” an existing word? Or should I use ‘illustrator’ instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a legitimately formed term, combining "illustration" and the suffix ["-ist"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ist).  But, since the term "illustrator" exists and is commonly used, that is preferred.  You might still want to use "illustrationist" in some cases since it tends to imply a more exceptional talent than the mundane "illuatrator".

Comment: It's a bit like that John Wayne movie called "The Shootist" rather than "The Shooter" (or "The Gunslinger"). It has some novelty value.

Comment: @JamesRandom [Bingo](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xf3mBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&dq=illustrationist&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6iZiTz_bcAhWKhlQKHd9tBYEQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=illustrationist&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. You should use **illustrator**. The artiest who express their thoughts through illustration is called **Illustrator**.

## illustrator

Excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illustrator):

> An **illustrator** is an artist who specializes in enhancing writing or elucidating concepts by providing a visual representation that corresponds to the content of the associated text or idea.

**Illustrationist** is grammatically correct, but not a vogue word.